# Zsh completion of hadoop commands

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Hadoop has a [range](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options) of commands and subcommands to specify different operations on MapReduce, HFS etc.  (e.g. `hadoop dfs` can be followed by any command from this list).

Is there any way to enable completion of these commands in Zsh?

In case it helps, I am using [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upstream zsh doesn't have a completion function for hadoop, so your choices are to find someone who wrote one for hadoop or to write your own.

If you are new to writing completion functions, ft wrote a nice introduction [here](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/).

The fastest way to learn in my opinion is to read and understand existing functions. since hadoop have subcommands, relevant existing functions are _zfs, _btrfs, _git and other commands that have the concept of `subcommands`. You can view them with `$EDITOR $^fpath/_zfs(N)`

the zsh userguide also have a chapter dedicated to how completion works [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html), and `man 1 zshcompsys` will quickly become your best friend.

And it is called `completion`, there is nothing `auto` about it :P